# appengine and no-ip.org

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I'd like to run an appengine app on a subdomain 
like something.no-ip.org instead of something.appspot.com 
is this doable? If so, can you please help me understand? :)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Consider buying a domain name. .com domains are under $10 a year and .info domains are less than $1 a year from GoDaddy.

Comment: thanks Ryan, but I don't want to use a TLD actually. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I believe http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47945 will answer this question! Yes, you can use no-ip. Still researching this, but it is by using CNAME. I'm looking for a way to use my no-ip subdomain as my email (ex. xxxxxx@xxxx.hopto.org).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, I haven't tried myself.

The steps you would follow are:

1. register something.no-ip.org with no-ip.org
2. sign up for something.no-ip.org with google apps standard
3. create your www.something.no-ip.org cname
4. in the google apps domain manager, enable google app engine for www.something.no-ip.org and map an app to the www cname.

This link is helpful for creating cnames and registering something.no-ip.org with google apps standard: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47945

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, because you don't own no-ip.org. In order to use a domain with App Engine, you have to set up Google Apps on the domain, and in order to do that, you must own the domain.

As mentioned in the comments, buying your own domain is your best option.

Comment: He is not saying he is going to set up google apps for no-ip.org, but for something.no-ip.org - which google apps will allow you to do.  He will own something.no-ip.org, which complies with the terms of service.

Comment: I doubt it's possible to register Apps on a subdomain of a domain you don't own - and even if it is, he would have to serve off foo.something.no-ip.org, since Apps doesn't permit serving off 'naked' domains.

Comment: It is possible, and even suggested on the google apps signup page itself.  Further, he will own the subdomain since he will be paying for it (as the free one is for personal use only).  Although the terms clearly state, 'own or control', since often no one actually owns domain names, and merely licenses said names for use of a license term of one year.

Comment: It's possible _if_ no-ip.org lets you set records on the subdomain, not just a single CNAME or A record. And that still doesn't solve the problem that he won't be able to host his App Engine app off the 'naked' domain.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can run App Engine apps on your own domain.  You need to have previously installed Google Apps for your domain:

```
http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new
```

After you do that, here are the steps:

1. Create your App Engine app and upload it.  You will get a default site on appid.appspot.com.
2. Log in to your AppEngine account at http://appengine.google.com/
3. Select your application to go to the management console.
4. Click on "Versions" link in the left column
5. Click the Add Domain button
6. Type your domain name (that you own) and click Add Domain...

This will take you to your Google Apps for Domains account manager, where you can add your AppEngine app to your account, and associate it with the sub-domain of your choosing (like www.your-domain.com).

Note that you'll also need to update your DNS settings to point your new domain to Google.  For example, if you want www.your-domain.com to point to your App Engine application, you'll need to add a CNAME record at your domain registrar to point to 'ghs.google.com'.

Note that App Engine DOES NOT support hosting your app at a 'naked domain', e.g., directly at 'your-domain.com'.  But, if you use GoDaddy (and most other registrars), you can redirect all requests to 'your-domain.com' to go to the equivalent URL on 'www.your-domain.com'.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html clearly states that "To begin, you'll need to sign up for Google Apps. If you don't already own your domain, you can use Google Apps to register it." -- something.no-ip.org is a subdomain of no-ip.org, not a domain.

Comment: Yes Artagnon, but isn't there a possibility to add no-ip.org and use a subdomain "something" since we acn't use naked domains anyway?

Comment: Theoretically, it should be possible. After all, it is a DNS entry- And no-ip.org allows you to add DNS entries for subdomains. From what I can see on that page, Google doesn't allow you to use subdomians of domains that aren't registered under Google Apps... and no-ip.org certainly isn't.

Comment: You could use "naked" domains by setting up your www subdomain to use AppEngine and then setup your DNS to redirect all requests without a subdomain to the www subdomain.